# Рандом в Python

Tags: python, случайные-числа

```
num = (random.randint(1000000, 9999999))
```

Сейчас у меня такой рандом, но мне надо чтобы этот рандом не начинался с млн а было 7значным
то есть так

```
0007895
```

а сейчас у меня так

```
1021581
```

Как сделать 7значный рандом но чтоб он мог начинаться с 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вам строка нужна? тогда так:

```
import random

num = f"{random.randint(0, 9999999):07d}"

print(num)
```

а если число - то `07` и `7` - это одно и тоже, весь вопрос только в отображении и чем я написал выше